# Django: Use positional arguments & keyword arguments together

Tags: python, django

The approach here below wouldn't work as it's a `positional argument & keyword argument` in one function. I understood, generally, `kwargs` are better as you can 'mess' around with the order. But how do I have to change `request.POST` in order to use `kwargs`?

```
form_refund = RefundForm(
    order=order,
    request.POST,
)
```

Comment: `order=order` is a keyword argument and `request.POST` is a positional argument. All positional arguments must be placed before the first keyword argument. You have to rearrange your init method to accept first `request.POST` and after that the keyword argument `order`. This is a general python question and not specific to Django.

Comment: `def __init__(self, *args, order, **kwargs)`that order worked for me now. Is this the way you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comment I have a better insight of what you're trying to do.

I suppose your init method looks something like:

```
def __init__(self, order=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

Therefore you're trying to call `RefundForm(order=order, request.POST)`, where `request.POST` is a positional argument, one of `*args`.

You're idea to rewrite it like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs, order):
```

won't work either. Here `order` is a positional argument defined after `*args` and `**kwargs`.

In my opinion the best approach would be the following:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    order = kwargs.pop('order', None)
```

Now you can instantiate an object with the call `RefundForm(request.POST, order=order)`. Here `order=order` is a keyword argument and is covered by `**kwargs`.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you cezar! Just as a note if anyone tries the same, I first wrote kwargs.pop after `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` but that won't work. It has to be before super().

Answer (score 0):

All your positional args need to come before keyword arguments. As `request.POST` is positional, it needs to be placed before `order=order`.

`form_refund = RefundForm(
    request.POST,
    order=order,
)`

If you don't know what is the right way to initialize your function, you can do it in 2 ways:

`def __init__(self, request)`:

or can also add keyword argument to initialization and set default value to it

`def __init__(self, request, order=None)`: